# Cannot set property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I want to set variable at store. 
Here is my store

```
class storeCategory{

    @observable categories =[];

    @action getCategories = () =>{
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/categories')
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(resp2){
            this.categories=resp2;
        });
    }


}
```

here is my component

```
@inject('sCategory')
@observer
class Category extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount=()=>{
       this.props.sCategory.getCategories();
    }

    render(){
        const {sCategory} = this.props;
        return (
            <ListGroup>
                {this.props.sCategory.categories.map((cat, index) => {
                            return (
                                <ListGroupItem key={cat.id}>{cat.categoryName}</ListGroupItem>
                            )
                        })}
            </ListGroup>
          );
    }
}
```

I add to **sCategory** to Provider at index.js

Im getting this error at **this.categories=resp2** in fetch method;

> Cannot set property 'categories' of undefined

Comment: This you get also if you call a property which is a function e.g. () is missing or too much. Yesterday i got crazy cause a variable was from type NUMBER and not as awaited a string (i just add +"" and everything was fine...). So the string function i was using was not defined for this variable value caus it was represented as number. And if you try to act on such a value which is handled by a "crippled function" she becomes "undefined" .Same happens if a function will not return anything .So check out whats going on at the place where it fails. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrow function instead:

```
@action getCategories = () =>{
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/categories')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((resp2) => {
        this.categories=resp2;
    });
}`
```

function keyword binds "this" keyword to itself, but arrow function keeps it bound to the context